# How to retrive cookie using @CookieValue in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, cookies, controller

When I am going to retrieve cookie using @CookieValue, it discards the last special char. Following is the code.

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public String root(@CookieValue(value="login", required=false) String myCookie) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    System.out.println("myCookie: "+myCookie);
    byte[] decoded = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(myCookie);
    String userName = new String(decoded, "UTF-8");
    // remaining code
    return "Test";
}

Output: myCookie: ZW1haWxAZXhhbXBsZS5jb20
```

and after decoding myCookie it shows `email@example.co` but the actual cookie is `ZW1haWxAZXhhbXBsZS5jb20=` and userName is `email@example.com`

I didn't get what the issue is.. Can someone help me..? Thanx.

Comment: Did you try use `HttpServletRequest` to get cookie. like this `request.getCookies()` this method return array of cookie. then you can loop throgh the array and find thevalue of cookie

Comment: You gotta check the cookie sent, because the current code works fine here. https://pastebin.com/PZHjMbQc

Comment: `@Raphael Amoedo` I check cookie and it is correctly created. As well as when I get cookie using javascript then it also shows correctly(with special char). But i didn't know what the problem with `@CookieValue`.